# How to remove index.php from codeigniter in Fast-cgi

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, fastcgi

Having problems with mod_rewrite in Fast-cgi environment for CodeIgniter. My .htaccess looks like this :

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|images|css|js|robots\\.txt|favicon\\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

But I got an error ‘No input file specified’.

I changed to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works only with this one also :

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is that I still have the index.php on the URL, if I changed the configuration file application/config/config.php from $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = ''; I have a different error.

What I do wrong ?

Comment: I found the solution on the application/config/config.php, I changed $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; to $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Answer (score 1):

add the code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and config.php file change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


//find the below code   

$config['index_page'] = "index.php"

//replace with the below code

$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in .htaccess file, notice the question mark behind index.php, that's the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

find the below code in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

replace with the below code

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```